# Dyntopo destroying basemesh

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I guess I am relatively new to Blender, or at least don't have a ton of experience. I was trying a new way of making models I found out about where you make a basemesh out of metaballs, convert it to a mesh, and use it for sculpting. I haven't sculpted much before, but when I have, I've had problems with dynamic topology getting rid of detail instead of adding more. This time I was using a tutorial I found that said to make sure the settings were on constant detail and resolution 12. Mine hadn't been set to this so I thought it might fix the problem. I put my basemesh into sculpt mode and fixed the dyntopo settings.

[image]

But when I try to use dyntopo, it is still destroying the mesh. I can use the brush and it actually adds more detail now, but I don't really think it's completely doing what it's supposed to. I makes the rest of the mesh look kind of low-poly. I would have to go over the whole thing with the brush to smooth it back out.

Here is the basemesh before I try dyntopo:

[image]

And this is after:

[image]

Here is the model in wireframe mode (before I go into sculpt mode and use dyntopo):

[image]

Would anyone be able to tell me what the problem is, and if there is a way to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: As soon as you activate Dyntopo, you can't see Shade Smooth nor Subdivision Surface modifier anymore, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: Moonboots - I didn't use any modifiers for the basemesh. It's just a lot of metaballs. I don't think I had smooth shading on. Honestly I don't know all that much about all the different settings though.

Comment: could you please show your wireframe before you switch to Sculpt mode? or share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure, I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: I've added the picture.

Comment: so it doesn't look so different than what we see after, except the shading is smooth and perhaps you've given a Subdivision Surface to your object, but both won't work when you'll enable Dyntopo

Comment: Okay, so I haven't used any modifiers, so no subdivision surface. I may have smooth shading on. What menu is that in? Also, when I go back to object mode, it still looks like it does after using dyntopo.

Comment: always keep a low-poly version of your object before sculpting (Shift D to duplicate). To change the shading, in Object mode, right click > Shade Smooth (or Shade Flat if you want the flat shading)

Comment: Yeah I have a copy. I tried shade flat and it still doesn't look like what dyntopo was doing. Still not sure what's going on. Thanks though.

Comment: maybe share your file?

Comment: So, I'm not sure exactly what I did, but it works now. Thanks for your help! This is my first time posting here, so I don't really know how it works. Do I need to close this question or something?

Comment: no, leave it as it is, if you've found the solution yourself and if you're able to explain you can write an answer in the Your Answer field

Comment: Over your first image you did not check "smooth shading" also 12 in constant Detail is really low.